# How do I convert an integer, stored in a variable, into a floating point, and store it in a different variable (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, nasm

I'm working on converting a decimal to a binary digit in NASM. I've got the integer 234 stored in a variable, let's call it dcml, and I want to convert to .234. What do I have to do?

I'm very new to assembly, so I've tried using different operands, such as fild, fld, and fst, but nothing seems to be working, at least with what I've been trying. The prof's examples are disorganized and I can't really follow it well, I just want to be able to understand what is going on with int -> float.

```
mov    rax,0
mov    rax,[num]   ; stores the 234
fild   qword[num]  
fst    qword[num]
mov    [dcml],rax  ; needs to be .234
```

The expected outcome, when printf'd, should be ".234", but it comes out as "234"

Comment: That's not just a conversion. You want to divide by 1000. Just because you do `(double)234` it's still `234` just in floating point format.

Comment: @Jester, would that look like a "fdiv   qword[thousand]" ?

Comment: Yes, assuming your `thousand` is in double precision format in memory. If it's an integer you want `fidiv`.

Comment: x86-64 makes SSE2 baseline, you don't need and shouldn't use x87.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
double fun ( int64_t, int64_t );
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%lf\n",fun(234,1000));
    return(0);
}

#include <stdint.h>
double fun ( int64_t x, int64_t y )
{
    return((double)x/y);
}
```

(compile then disassemble)

you need to convert to double (234.0) then divide by (double) 1000.0 to get (double) 0.234

look at cvtsi2sd and divsd

Comment: x86-64 System V passes the first 2 integer args in RDI, RSI.  If your compiler used EDI, ESI, it's broken and truncating `int64_t` to `int32_t`.  But yes, `cvtsi2sd` with qword operand-size is what you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's using `edi` and `esi` because the numbers are smaller than 2³¹, not because the compiler is defective.

Comment: So, out of interest, what compiler and version is broken?

Comment: @fuz: oh, I didn't notice there was a caller with compile-time-constant args.  That's silly, it just lets the function inline and optimize away when you enable optimization to find out how to do the operation efficiently.  I thought old_timer was talking about the function of interest, not the caller.

Comment: @old_timer: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) quotes the relevant section of Intel's manual